# How to create a 2D Array countdown with different line length?

Tags: arrays, 2d

I have a little problem to understand the following task.
I should create a 2D Array like this:

```
n = 4
```

-->

```
[4,4,4,4]

[3,3,3]

[2,2]

[1]
```

I need only a hint how to create this 2D Array with different line length, so that i can return it in the method:

```
static int[][] arrayCountDown(int n) {...}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    static int[][] arrayCountDown(int n){

        int[][] array = new int[n][];
        for( int i=0;i<n;i++){
            array[i] = new int[n-i];
            for(int j=0;j<n-i;j++){
                array[i][j] = n-i;

            }

        }
       return array;
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is incorrect. 
I need an 2D Array where the first line is for example if n = 4, length 4, the second line is length 3, and so on. 
so if i print it with Arrays.toString(arrayCountDown(n)) it gives the result from above.

Do you understand?
But thanks for your help.

Comment: Fixed it now. Check it out now.

Comment: Thank you so much, i didnt know that i can make an empty array like " new int[n][ ] " and I have not found a solution anywhere.

Also i have my problems to understand multidimensional Arrays,but this solution has given me a new understanding.

Thx.

Answer (score 0):

If there are `n` levels, then there are `n*(n+1)/2` elements in total. But that doesn't matter as you just fill in as you go

In `C#` world the solution is:

```
static int[][] arrayCountDown(int n) 
{
    var array = new int[n][];
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
         int num = n-i;
         int[] row = new int[num];
         for(int k=0; k<num; k++)
         {
             row[k] = num;
         }
         array[i] = row;
    }
    return array;
}
```